# Выделить страну/регион/город в Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Как выделить (закрасить) страну/регион/город в Google maps?
При выборе города через сервис Google, он автоматически выделяет его 
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Не могу понять как сделать это через API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через API это сделать невозможно. По крайней мере на данный момент.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй для этого файлы формата KML 
http://habrahabr.ru/post/197448/